# Mute flowplayer on click on custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I'm using the flash version of FlowPlayer and I need to allow users to toggle the sound of the player when they click on a button in the page.

I've read the [documentation about the API](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html) and the function should be:

```
mute([flag])
```

But I can't understand how to call it within a jQuery `on()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation link in your question is actually to the HTML5 player and not the Flash player.  The ability to mute a video from a custom button is still available in the Flash version and the API docs can be found here - [flowplayer JavaScript API](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html)

`mute()` is a method available on the player, and also `unmute()` and can be used like this:

**Usage**

```
$f('player').mute();
$f('player').unmute();
```